# Perform Operation in Synchronized manner using OperationQueue

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsoperationqueue

I am performing the same get call with different parameters inside a loop. Here is my code:

```
for (Printer* printer in responsePrinterList){

    NSURLComponents *components = [NSURLComponents componentsWithString:notification_count];
    NSURLQueryItem *assetId = [NSURLQueryItem queryItemWithName:@"assetId" value:[printer printerHash]];
    NSURLQueryItem *count = [NSURLQueryItem queryItemWithName:@"state" value:@"active"];
    components.queryItems = @[ assetId, count];
    NSURL *url = components.URL;
    NSString* urlString = url.absoluteString;
    UrlRequest *urlRequest = [[UrlRequest alloc] initUrlRequestWithURL:urlString setHTTPBody:nil shouldHandleCookies:NO isHTTPMethodPost:NO withTimeoutInterval:30];

    NSString *authorizationKey = access_token;
    NSString *authorizationValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bearer %@",authorizationKey];
    [urlRequest addValue:@"application/json;charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [urlRequest addValue:authorizationValue forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

    UrlSession *urlSession = [[UrlSession alloc] initUrlSession];
    self.eccUserInfoOp = [[InvocationOperation alloc] initInvocationOpearationWithTarget:self selector:@selector(SuccessWithData:) object:nil urlSession:urlSession urlRequest:urlRequest];
    self.eccUserInfoOp.failedInvocation = [self.eccUserInfoOp createInvocationWithTarget:self selector:@selector(FailedWithData:)];
    //[self.eccOperationQueue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:1];
    [self.operationQueue addOperation:self.eccUserInfoOp];
 }
```

Below is the code for my OperationQueue class

**OperationQueue.h**

```
@interface OperationQueue : NSOperationQueue

+ (instancetype)sharedInstanceOfOperationQueue;

@end
```

**OperationQueue.m**

```
@implementation OperationQueue
+ (instancetype)sharedInstanceOfOperationQueue {
    static dispatch_once_t onceOfOperationQueue;
    static id sharedInstanceOfOperationQueue;
    dispatch_once(&onceOfOperationQueue, ^{
        sharedInstanceOfOperationQueue = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedInstanceOfOperationQueue;
}


@end
```

My requirement is these individual get call are performed in the same order as I call them inside my loop i.e the response for first printer in list should return first and then the second printer and so on.

I am not sure how to make my Operation Queue serial and achieve this.

Comment: See `maxConcurrentOperationCount`.

Comment: @PhillipMills, see my updated answer. I tried using that but the I don't get any response when I do that. Am I using it at the right place?? Check the commented line in above code.

Comment: You should only need to set it when you create your queue.  I'd have tried it inside the `dispatch_once` block where you do the init.